# arrow break down to the next line in IE11

Tags: html, css, internet-explorer-11

I have a arrow at the end of my sentence. It is breaking down to the next line when there not enough space. It breaks down to the next line with the word in browser like chrome and mozilla but in IE only arrow breaks to the next line.  It should have the same behaviour like other browser do[fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/app8n6ow/1/)

Chrome screenshot

[image]

IE11 screenshot

[image]

**HTML**

```
 <div>See your operating system's help resources</div>
```

**CSS**

```
div{ width:50%; border:solid 1px #ff0000}
div:after{ content:">"; margin-left:5px}
```

Comment: I tried it on Edge, IE11, and Chrome it works on all of them. I couldn't make the arrow break to the next line alone

Comment: yes, I have checked on IE11 -  couldn't make the arrow break to next line. Once check which IE version you getting this issue

Comment: I am getting this issue on IE11

Answer (score 0):

I couldn't add an image in comment 
so check this screen shot from IE11
[image]

Comment: It is because there is not space even for "resources" word. Try to resize it slowly then you can see the bug

Comment: @Carlos I tried to resize slowly but couldn't recreate the issue

Answer (score 0):

You might try a *non-breaking space* (`&nbsp;`).

**HTML**

```
<div>See your operating system's help resources</div>
```

**CSS**

```
div {width:50%; border:solid 1px #ff0000;}
div:after {content:"\00a0\003e";}
```

---

**Edit:** *Replaced* `div:after {content:"&nbsp;&gt;";}` *with* `div:after {content:"\00a0\003e";}`

Comment: in html it is display like See your operating system's help resources&nbsp;&gt;"

Comment: Sorry, Carlos - my mistake. I forgot that the `content:` in CSS `:before` & `:after` pseudo-elements takes UTF-8 escape sequences, not standard HTML escape characters.